# Store output of ForEach into array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, output

```
$data = @("server1","server2","server3")

foreach ($server in $data) {
    $results = (Test-Connection $server -count 1 | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).Average
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to take the output of a ForEach and store the results into an array so I may then compare them later. I could not come up with a way to do this yet.

Comment: `$results = @( ForEach ( ... ) { ... } )`

Comment: @PetSerAl, whats the difference between `$results = @( foreach ...)` and `$results = foreach ...`, doesn't it return array anyway? also, shouldn't `foreach` return something, for this to work?

Comment: @4c74356b41 `@()` always return array. Even in case of zero or one item.

Comment: so how does a zero length array help compare results?

Comment: @4c74356b41 It helps by eliminating special case, when with zero items PowerShell does not return array by default.

Comment: yes, i understand that, but the goal of this person is to compare the results to something, not get an array, if the `foreach` doesn't return anything, he won't get what he wants, right?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Sorry, I do not understand your point. I can ask it other way: Is any benefit of not using `@()`, apart of saving three keystrokes? My default is to use `@()`, when I expect multiple return from the statement, just to be on safe side, especially in reusable scripts. And, BTW, `compare 1,2,3 @()` vs `compare 1,2,3 $null`.

Comment: welp, I was talking about the fact, that you should actually return some data in the `foreach` loop, else you will always get empty array as a result? his example doesn't return anything, so... he will always get empty array, even if he actually pings something.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $FinalResult = @()
    $data = @("server1","server2","server3")
    foreach ($server in $data) {
        $results = (Test-Connection $server -count 1 | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).Average

        $FinalResult += New-Object psobject -Property @{
                        ServerName = $server
                        Result = $result
                        }  
    }
   $FinalResult | Select ServerName, Result | Export-Csv ".\FinalResult.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Please let me  know if this snippet doesn't work, i will do the needful.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient because appending creates a new array every single loop, resulting in a time complexity of O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

By doing the `ForEach`, you're just measuring the value of the property of a scalar (single) object. The average will always be just the value of that property.

`Test-Connection` will accept an array of names as the -ComputerName parameter, so the ForEach isn't really necessary at all.

```
 $data = @("server1","server2","server3")

 $results = Test-Connection $data -count 1 | select -ExpandProperty ResponseTime
```

Comment: I used the example to get the concept of what I'm doing. I'm not using Test-Connection, but a more larger script, but the concept is the same.  Just need to figure out how to store results into an array while having it loop until there's no more inputs.

Comment: Then you already have your answer in the comments.  Simply redirect the foreach output to a variable, and Powershell will automatically build an array if it returns more than one object. You can force it to be an array using the @() syntax if that's necessary to prevent errors downstream in the case of it not returning multiple objects.